# Crystal Report: image on shared area

Tags: c#, iis-7, crystal-reports

I'm trying to show an image on a Report created with CR for VS2010. The image is stored on shared area and the path an file name are coming from a DB. On my VS it works fine and also if I try to publish the application under II7 on my local machine. The problem happens when I try to publish the application on II7 under Windows 2008 server: the image is not visible.

I checked if it's available on the shared are and it is and also the permssion are ok (visible to everyone).

what's wrong? Could you help me please?

thanks!
Andrea

Comment: your this report has this image only or it has some other data also?

Comment: Data and also an image. Data is shown correctly and I also print the image path and it's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case the problem was releted to the Image size. I didn't see the image on first page because I choose the resize option to true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resolve the issue by changing the application pool `Managed Pipeline Mode` to `Classic`.  It should be  originally set to `Integrated`. It is an `IIS` setting.